# I want to show all the http request and responses on logcat of android studio using okhttp. I am attching the code mainactivity.java

Tags: android-studio, http, network-programming, okhttp

It is a webview app i am working on android studio.
some part of code is below.

InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("https://" + editText.getText().toString());
                        editText.setText("");

Comment: See the [editing-help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to post code in your question.

Comment: And for the question part OkHTTP seems to be an HTTP client from the documentation. Are you sure you can achieve the logging with OkHTTP ? Moreover, the system security wont allow a normal user to do such activities (peeping on other apps traffic). You need to search for some libcap implementation for android. In linux thats how you log packets !